# Where can I delete previous permissions to a shared Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I've made a Google Sheet with App Script. When I share it with others, they have to authorize the script.

The problem is that I tried different methods, such as using Google Forms and Slides, but not in the final sheet, so now they have to authorize that the sheet can change forms and slides, which doesn't look good and can create confusion.

How can I change these authorizations?

Answer (score 2):

The authorization is triggered automatically based on the current script. If you have form or slide calls(**even if commented out**), it'll trigger authorization with such scopes included. Consider removing stray comments. Alternatively, [edit the appsscript.json to limit oAuthScopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)